# Automatic email on TFS Build 2012

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS 2012 and have a build server setup.  I would like to send out an email when a certain build is complete.  In this email I would like to send out a list of the Associated Changesets and Associated Work Items. In the build template I call a script to deploy the build.  At that time the log file is not available.

Is there a way I can run a script after the build so that I can read the log file, or is there another way for me to access the Associated Changesets and Associated Work Items for the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe an alert for a build definition like following screenshot, when there is a build completed, you'll receive an email alert.

[image]

If there are associated Changesets and associated Work Items in the build, you'll see them in the email alert:

[image]

Useful link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334(v=vs.110).aspx